Convert C# REGEX to Oracle PLSQL REGEX
I'm trying to convert a C# REGEX into a Oracle PLSQL compatible REGEX.
This REGEX was used to validate e-mail address format.
C# REGEX
[\w!#$%&’*+\-=?\^_`{|}~]+(\.[\w!#$%&’*+\-=?\^_`{|}~]+)*@((([\-\w]+\.)+[\w]{2,})|(([0-9]1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}))

Oracle 19c Version 19.20.0.0.0
I tried different stuff and came up with the below expression,
Oracle PLSQL REGEX
^[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+\-\/=?\^_`{|}~]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+\-\/=?\^_`{|}~]+)*@((([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,})|(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}))$

But the test results doesn't match the below test case,

example@s.example - This is an invalid email address

Can someone please help me to convert the C# REGEX into a Oracle PLSQL compatible REGEX?

Do not use \w and other shorthand character classes inside bracket expressions.

[\w!#$%&’*+\-=?\^_\{|}~]should be[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&’*+=?^`{|}~-](swap\wfora-zA-Z0-9, remove the \ escape characters and move -` to the end).

However, example+"test"@gmail.com is a valid e-mail and your pattern will not match it.
